# Python minimax algorithm implementation not working for tic tac toe

Tags: python, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have written a basic game of tic tac toe and attempted to implement the minimax algorithm for the game's ai. However, the algorithm does not seem to be working properly when the script is run. 
Example:     (the ai is O )

```
|X|X| |
-------
| | | |
-------
| |O| |
-------
```

results in

```
|X|X| |
-------
| | |O|
-------
| |O| |
-------
```

As well as this, the algorithm will often overwrite the player's previous moves

Complete script

```
import random
import time
import sys
from sys import maxsize




#converts numbers from the board to X O and "" for printing out the board 
def numToSymbol(board):
    visual = board
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if visual[i] == -1:
            visual[i]= "X"
        elif visual[i] == 1:
            visual[i] = "O"
        elif visual[i] == 0:
            visual[i] = " "
    return visual


def symbolToNum(visual):
    board = visual
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if board[i] == "X":
            board[i] = -1
        elif board[i] == "O":
            board[i] = 1
        elif board[i] == " ":
            board[i] = 0
    return board


# prints the board, first coverting numbers throught numtoSymbol
def drawBoard():
    visual = numToSymbol(board)
    print(
        "|"+ str(visual[0]) + "|" + str(visual[1]) + "|" + str(visual[2]) + "| \n"
        "-------\n"
        "|"+ str(visual[3]) + "|" + str(visual[4]) + "|" + str(visual[5]) + "| \n"
        "-------\n"
        "|"+ str(visual[6]) + "|" + str(visual[7]) + "|" + str(visual[8]) + "| \n"
        "-------")
    symbolToNum(visual)


# checks the possible options for 3 in a row and if any are all held by one side returns true
def checkWin(board, winConditions, ai):
    if ai == True:
        win = 3
    if ai == False:
        win = -3
    for row in winConditions:
        checkA = board[row[0]]
        checkB = board[row[1]]
        checkC = board[row[2]]
        if checkA + checkB + checkC == int(win):
           return True

    return False

def checkDraw(board):
    emptyTile = 9
    for tile in board:
        if tile != 0:
            emptyTile -= 1
    if emptyTile == 0:
        completion(2)

def availableMoves(board, bonus):
    availableSlots = []
    for position in range(0,9):
        if board[position] == 0:
            availableSlots.append(position + bonus)
    return availableSlots



def playerTurn(board, remainingTurns):
    board = board
    checkDraw(board)
    visual =drawBoard()
    print("pick one of the available slots \n")
    availableSlots = availableMoves(board, 1)
    print(availableSlots)
    choice = int(input('Select a tile from those shown above:\n')) -1
    while  True:    
        if 0 <= choice <= 8:
            if board[choice] == 0:
                board[choice] = -1
                break
            else:
                choice = int(input('Select a tile from those shown above which has not already been selected:\n')) -1
        else:
            choice = int(input('Select a tile from those shown above:\n')) -1
    visual = drawBoard()
    if checkWin(board, winConditions, False) == True:
        completion(0)
    else:
        aiTurn(board, remainingTurns - 1)


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,  remainingTurns, playerNum, board, value = 0):
        self.depth = remainingTurns
        self.playerNum = playerNum
        self.board = board[::]
        self.value = value
        self.moves = availableMoves(self.board, 0)
        self.children = []
        self.createChildren()

    def availableMoves(self, board):
        self.availableSlots = []
        for position in range(0,9):
            if board[position] == 0:
                availableSlots.append(position)
        return self.availableSlots

    def winCheck(self, state, playerNum):
        self.winConditions = [[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8],[0, 3, 6],[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[0, 4, 8],[2, 4, 6]]
        self.win = 3
        for row in self.winConditions:
            self.checkA = self.state[row[0]]
            self.checkB = self.state[row[1]]
            self.checkC = self.state[row[2]]
            if self.checkA + self.checkB + self.checkC == int(self.win * self.playerNum):
               return True
        return False

    def createChildren(self):
        if self.depth > 0:
            for i in self.moves:
                self.state = self.board
                self.state[i] = self.playerNum
                print(board)
                self.children.append(Node(self.depth - 1, self.playerNum * -1, self.state, self.realVal(self.state, self.playerNum) ))


    def realVal(self, value, playerNum):
        value = self.winCheck(self.state, self.playerNum)
        if value == True:
            return maxsize * self.playerNum
        else:
            return 0




def minimax(node, depth, playerNum):
    if depth == 0 or abs(node.value) == maxsize:
        return node.value

    bestValue = maxsize * -playerNum

    for i in range(len(node.children)):
        child = node.children[i]
        val = minimax(child, depth - 1, -playerNum)
        if (abs(maxsize * playerNum - val) < abs(maxsize * playerNum - bestValue)):
            bestValue = val
    return bestValue


def aiTurn(board, remainingTurns):
    checkDraw(board)
    print('Waiting for ai')
    time.sleep(2)
    board = board
    state = board
    currentPlayer = 1
    tree = Node(remainingTurns, currentPlayer, state)
    bestChoice = -100
    bestValue = maxsize * -1
    for i in range(len(tree.children)):
        n_child = tree.children[i]
        i_val = minimax(n_child, remainingTurns, -currentPlayer,)
        if (abs(currentPlayer * maxsize - i_val) <= abs(currentPlayer * maxsize - bestValue)):
            bestValue = i_val
            bestChoice = i
    print(bestChoice)
    board[bestChoice] = 1
    if checkWin(board, winConditions, True) == True:
        completion(1)
    else:
        playerTurn(board, remainingTurns - 1)



def completion(state):
    if state == 1:
        print('The computer has won this game.')
        choice = str(input('press y if you would like to play another game; Press n if you would not \n'))
        if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
            playGame()
        else:
            sys.exit()
    if state == 0:
        print('you win!')
        choice = str(input('press y if you would like to play another game; Press n if you would not \n'))
        if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
            playGame()
        else:
            sys.exit()
    if state == 2:
        print('you drew')
        choice = str(input('press y if you would like to play another game; Press n if you would not \n'))
        if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
            playGame()
        else:
            sys.exit()        




def playGame():
    global board
    board = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    global winConditions
    winConditions = [
                [0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8],
                [0, 3, 6],
                [1, 4, 7],
                [2, 5, 8],
                [0, 4, 8],
                [2, 4, 6]
                ]


    global remainingTurns
    remainingTurns = 9
    playerFirst = random.choice([True, False])

    if playerFirst == True:
        playerTurn(board, remainingTurns)
    else:
        aiTurn(board, remainingTurns)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    playGame()
```

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? What did you learn as a result? What problems are you facing in making progress during your debugging? If you were hoping that you could just dump your code on somebody else and have them do all the work for you, you need to adjust your expectations.